# Trying to access local HTML files through .desktop files

Tags: ubuntu-touch, .desktop, html

I am trying to follow the instructions given to another user (jurjen) by building the following .local/share/applications/.desktop file, and also variations of it. It does not produce any button anywhere. I've done a shallow research on .desktop files to refine a previous version. I am clearly blindly missing the big points.

```
    phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ cat .local/share/applications/.desktop 
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Name=web container
    Type=Application
    Exec=/usr/bin/webapp-container --enable-addressbar --enable-back-forward --webappUrlPatterns=/home/phablet/*/*/* /home/phablet/*/* /home/phablet/* /home/phablet/
    Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/32/add.svg
    Terminal=false
    X-Ubuntu-Touch=true


    phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$
```

Comment: See this: > http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Finally, what I was missing is that .desktop is not a file name but an extension. Now, my foo.desktop file works fine; I'll have to change it until it does not work anew, just to learn. But this triggers a new question...  (on a different subject).

Comment: My answer comes from a clue posted by this site.   I do love this site.